# linux kernel scheduler CFS

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, scheduling

How does linux kernel's  CFS scheduler schedule all the process within sched_latency_ns time.
Is it by traversing though the red black tree or re balancing after every process switch.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_Fair_Scheduler) article...

> In contrast to the previous O(1) scheduler used in older Linux 2.6 kernels, the CFS scheduler implementation is not based on run queues. Instead, a red-black tree implements a "timeline" of future task execution. Additionally, the scheduler uses nanosecond granularity accounting, the atomic units by which an individual process' share of the CPU was allocated (thus making redundant the previous notion of timeslices). This precise knowledge also means that no specific heuristics are required to determine the interactivity of a process, for example.[2]

Comment: i have gone through all these docs,but nowhere its specified how its done.Can any one explain how the this minimum slice is assigned to each process??

Answer (score 1):

[here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-cfs/) describe CFS in details together with snippet source code.

Comment: The link above is broken, but I think he is referring to http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-completely-fair-scheduler/index.html

Answer (score 0):

CFS picks the leftmost node out of rbtree with O(1) complexity because it is cached. Then CFS gives it the time share.

If the task completes, then CFS just finishes it up.

If it has not completed, but the time share runs out OR it volunteers to stop (waiting for IO reading, writing, network packets...). It's now inserted to rbtree again with O(logN) complexity, and rebalancing if needed.